# widget problems on Samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: android, widget, galaxy

We released a new app which has a widget. This works fine so far on all devices, however on Samsung Galaxy S3 we get reports that it stops working in certain situations.

Unfortunately I do not have such a device to check myself - therefore I would just like to know if anyone had some similar experience.

The widget stops working after the screen redraws itself (which seems to happen on the S3 regularly and randomly). Another user reported that the widget stops working after invoking the Task Manager and "clearing memory". There is no crash - in this case unfortunately.

The app has been tested on many devices with different Android versions - so far we have never seen such a random screen update which caused the widget to stop working.

I am thankfull for any hints.

Comment: These reports should come with stack traces, do you have one?

Comment: ...no these are just user emails of some very helpful and friendly app users - there is no crash

Comment: I have no idea. Best I can say is to put a whole bunch of logs into the app and ask these helpful users to help you debug. I can't imagine any other way to help them without getting a device and testing it for yourself.

Comment: now I also tested several S3 - always the same problem! with Android 4.0.4 BUT on Samsung S2 or HTC with same Android version there is no problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...in fact it turned out to be a fault in Samsung's Android implemenation - they promised to fix it in the upcoming release. Thanks to Samsung amazing support we finally could confirm this issue !